# hibernate error log in tomcat 8 org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Unable to compile class for JSP

Tags: java, hibernate, tomcat, netbeans

## Stacktrace:] with root cause

please do help me soon as possible. thanks

### what is the error , this is my first hibernate program. plz anyone help me

```
 org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Unable to compile class for JSP: 

An error occurred at line: 10 in the jsp file: /Display.jsp
Session cannot be resolved to a type
7: 
8: <%@ page import="java.util.*,com.model.*,org.hibernate.*,org.hibernate.cfg.*" %>
9: 
10: <%! int empid;String gender; String dept;String address; String name;Long phnum; Session session1 = null; %>
11: <body>
12: <table width="220" border="1">
13:     <form action="./delEmp.jsp">


An error occurred at line: 16 in the jsp file: /Display.jsp
```

### Configuration cannot be resolved to a type

```
13:     <form action="./delEmp.jsp">
14:     <tr><th>EMPID</th><th>NAME</th><th>GENDER</th><th>DEPT</th><th>ADDRESS</th><th>PHONENUMBER</th></tr>        
15: <%
16: Configuration cf=new Configuration();
17: cf.configure();
18: SessionFactory sf = cf.buildSessionFactory();
19: session1 =sf.openSession();


An error occurred at line: 16 in the jsp file: /Display.jsp
```

### Configuration cannot be resolved to a type

```
13:     <form action="./delEmp.jsp">
14:     <tr><th>EMPID</th><th>NAME</th><th>GENDER</th><th>DEPT</th><th>ADDRESS</th><th>PHONENUMBER</th></tr>        
15: <%
16: Configuration cf=new Configuration();
17: cf.configure();
18: SessionFactory sf = cf.buildSessionFactory();
19: session1 =sf.openSession();


An error occurred at line: 18 in the jsp file: /Display.jsp
```

### SessionFactory cannot be resolved to a type

```
15: <%
16: Configuration cf=new Configuration();
17: cf.configure();
18: SessionFactory sf = cf.buildSessionFactory();
19: session1 =sf.openSession();
20: //Using from Clause
21: String SQL_QUERY ="from Employee";


An error occurred at line: 19 in the jsp file: /Display.jsp
```

### session1 cannot be resolved to a variable

```
16: Configuration cf=new Configuration();
17: cf.configure();
18: SessionFactory sf = cf.buildSessionFactory();
19: session1 =sf.openSession();
20: //Using from Clause
21: String SQL_QUERY ="from Employee";
22: Query query = session1.createQuery(SQL_QUERY);


An error occurred at line: 22 in the jsp file: /Display.jsp
```

### Query cannot be resolved to a type

```
19: session1 =sf.openSession();
20: //Using from Clause
21: String SQL_QUERY ="from Employee";
22: Query query = session1.createQuery(SQL_QUERY);
23: Iterator it=query.iterate();
24: while(it.hasNext())
25: {


An error occurred at line: 22 in the jsp file: /Display.jsp
```

### session1 cannot be resolved

```
19: session1 =sf.openSession();
20: //Using from Clause
21: String SQL_QUERY ="from Employee";
22: Query query = session1.createQuery(SQL_QUERY);
23: Iterator it=query.iterate();
24: while(it.hasNext())
25: {


An error occurred at line: 47 in the jsp file: /Display.jsp
```

### session1 cannot be resolved

```
44: </tr>
45: <%
46: }
47: session1.close();
48: %>
49: <tr>
50:     <th colspan="5" align="right"><input type="submit" value="delete"></th>
```

### Stacktrace:

```
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.DefaultErrorHandler.javacError(DefaultErrorHandler.java:103)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.javacError(ErrorDispatcher.java:199)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.JDTCompiler.generateClass(JDTCompiler.java:450)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:361)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:336)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:323)
    at org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:564)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:357)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:396)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:340)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:725)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:501)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:142)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:610)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:537)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1085)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:658)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11NioProtocol.java:222)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1556)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1513)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: Can you tell us what you are using to build your project? Are you using Maven? Do you have all the required dependencies?

Comment: hiberbate,tomcat in netbeans

Comment: i do have all dependencies

Comment: Did you verify the java you are using is a jdk not just a jre?

Comment: Can you try to get your code working as a standalone? You cna make it a web application later?

Comment: okay will do try in standalone.

Comment: org.dom4j.DocumentException: C:\Users\user\Downloads\apache-tomcat-8.0.15\bin\null (The system cannot find the file specified) Nested exception: C:\Users\user\Downloads\apache-tomcat-8.0.15\bin\null (The system cannot find the file specified)
 o

Comment: i just clean and build my project now am getting the above error